# Identifying double/overlapping polygons using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, overlapping-features

I have two datasets in which the information about the area are deviating:

- an observation room with three corridors (A = 25000 ha, B = 30000 ha and C = 20000 ha)
- land use dataset provided by an external institution (A = 35000 ha, B= 45000 ha and C = 37500 ha)

I do not know how the land use data set was approached, but I assume that the result of it includes double or overlapping polygons. Can anyone show me a way, how to identify and delete those features t receive the same area as in the observation room.

I use an ArcGIS 10.3 basic license.

Comment: Here is solution for Advanced ArcInfo license: http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=1dd4a6832b3d40b494dbf8521cc5134c

Answer (score 2):

With a basic license, you can use the Union tool.

Union observation room and land use datasets with the union tool.

The output dataset will have the attribute fields from both datasets, as well as the original FID of each feature.  To find features that overlap, select all records where FID.Observation_Room <> -1 and FID.land_use <> -1.

You can then manipulate the attributes as needed.  Both tables will be joined in the union output.